# Exclude document from FirestorePagingOption

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of users and i want to exlclude that user does the research.
How can i solve? Thanks.

```
 query = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("city", city);
 PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                        .setPageSize(3)
                        .build();

 FirestorePagingOptions<User> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                        .setQuery(query, config, User.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't provide any way to exclude specific documents from the result of a query.  You can only filter documents based on data contained in its fields.  If you want to remove a document, you will have to write code on to remove it in your app, which means you also won't be able to use FirebaseUI to display the results.  You will have to write your own adapter to show the modified results.

Comment: So I can't use FirestorePagingAdapater but insted one RecyclerView.Adapter ? and how do I use the pagination?